# Single table inheritance with relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm trying to build a student portal in Rails 3, but I'm having some problem.

The idea is to have a users table that contains all basic data for a given person. See the UML/E-R below for example attributes.

- A user can be both an *Assistant* and a *Student* at the same time.
- *Assistant* and *Student* should inherit from *User*.

The idea was to inherit directly from the User, like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def awesome?
    [true, false].sample
  end
  # ...
end

class Student < User
  has_one :student
  has_many :registered_courses, through: :students
end

Student.new.awesome?
```

This makes the relations in the student model very strange.
`has_many :registered_courses, through: :students`

I want to be able to do something like this in the end.

```
student.full_name
student.pin_code
student.registered_courses
```

One solution would be to implementing the method by hand, like this

```
class Student < User 
  has_one :student 
  def pin_number
    student.pin_number
  end
end
```

But it looks really strange to refer to a student object inside the student model.

Is there a clearer, better way of doing this?

Here is an example UML/E-R. I've tried to keep this example clean by removing non relevant attributes. That is why there are so few attributes in the registered course entity.

[image: uml]

Comment: Why does table `Student` needs both `id` and `user_id`? Is this a Rails limitation?

Comment: The `id` isn't needed. I'm not sure why it's there.

Comment: Are there 2 or 4 tables in total? Single Table Inheritance should be 2... (both student and assistant should be the same user table). Your case seems like Multi Table Inheritance (if it is MTI, then you do not inherit the model......)

Comment: @PeterWong I'm not sure STI is applied to this particular setup, maybe MTI is better?

Comment: @Oleander If you do use STI, the consequence is you have to combine the students table, the assistants table and the users table into one users table. The good thing is STI in rails is a lot simpler than MTI. The bad thing is you would have a lot of null fields in the users table if you have a lot of student-specific / assistant-specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

STI is not a good choice for this the way that you have articulated it here, since users can be both students and assistants.  When you are using STI, you generally add a type column to specify which subclass the record really belongs to.  If both Student and Assistant inherit from User, then that really isn't an option, since you'd be forced to create duplicate User records for someone who is both an Assistant and a Student.

I think you'd be better off simply having Student and Assistant rows that belong_to a Student, and then delegating the elements that are contained in User back to the User object.

Comment: I still some how need to inherit from the user model. All logic inside the user model must be accessible inside a student or an assistant.

Comment: You can use delegate to make it look like the User logic is in the Student or Assistant.  For example, in your Student class, you could delegate :ssn, :email, :to  => :user

Answer (score 0):

I feel like Inheritance is a bad move here. If you're going to have STI like this it **HAS** to be one or the other.

Instead throw all your logic into the `User` model, all your data is there anyway. Plus since `Student` & `Assistant` aren't mutually exclusive there shouldn't be any methods that will override each other.

**Why not STI?**

STI is mainly meant for objects that contain the same data, but does different things with them.

For example, I have a specification that contains multiple processes(ex. build and test). So I have a `order` that contains `processes`.

```
process_1:
  order_id: 1
  specification: foo
  type: build

process_2:
  order_id: 1
  specification: foo
  type: test
```

In this example the only thing that changes in the data is the type, but because the type changes I know what `process` to perform from the specification.